# API for context managers

Tags: python, api-design, contextmanager

I have an object (say `FileProxy`) that looks like a file but does some extra work. It is initialised like so `foo = FileProxy("/some/file.txt")` and I can then use it like so

```
foo.open()
foo.write("something")
foo.close()
```

I want to make this work as a context manager. The question is whether I should make it work like this where the context manager does more than just creating the object but actually calls the `.open` method and `.close` upon exit.

```
with FileProxy("/some/file.txt") as f:
   f.write("something")
```

or should I do something like

```
with FileProxy("/some/file.txt").open() as f:
   f.write("something")
```

which is more symmetrical with the non context manager API.

I prefer the former myself but it looks different from the way regular files in Python work and I'm wondering if there's some anti pattern that I'm implementing here.

Comment: while I think this is great question to discuss, it ultimately is not *clearly* answerable, because it's answer is the result of deliberation of competing aspects to design, best practices, principle of least astonishment etc.

Comment: Agreed but I'd like some concrete points to base a (possible subjective) decision on.

Comment: I propose you end your question this way or similiar: "As you can see, I'm taking the file API as well as the context manage API in consideration. Also ... has to be reflected. Which principles / patterns / thoughts should I definitely also consider when deciding this?" - this is still opinionated, but people can focus on a principle per answer, which would lead (hopefully) to insighful, non-flamebait answers (there wouldn't be one true answer)

Comment: The former suits much better with `with`, because the reason i may be using the `FileProxy` class would be to operate on a file, thereby i would assume that the context manager would handle the opening and closing of the respective file.